# Proving $U_\epsilon = \{x \in M | d(x, C) < \epsilon\}$ is open, given that $C$ is non-empty

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> In a metric space $(M, d)$ let $C \subset M$ and non-empty. Given $\epsilon > 0$ we define:
>   $$
> U_\epsilon = \{x \in M | d(x, C) < \epsilon\}
> $$
>   Prove $U_\epsilon$ is open.

I am assuming $d(x,C) := inf\{d(x, c) | c \in C\}$.
I know I have to find $r > 0$ such that $B(x, r) \subset U_\epsilon$ , $\forall x \in U_\epsilon $ , but how can I find such $r$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $r:=\varepsilon-d(x,C)$.
$\!\!\!\!\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $